# How do I emit a socket.io event based on a Mongoose .save() callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, mongoose

Relatively new to Node / Mongoose / Socket.io and I'm stuck.  I have a two node processes running - index.js and person_saver.js.  When person_saver.js creates and saves a person, I want to emit an event to a client that's connected to index.js.  Seems like it should be straightforward, but can't figure it out.  Help appreciated!

**index.js**

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(client){

//Can person_saver.js use the client object from index.js?
//Alternately, can I trigger something here based on the person.save callback?

}
```

**person_saver.js**

```
var person = new Person({ first: 'Spider', last: 'Man', age: 23 });

person.save(function(err, person) {
    //client.emit('person-event', person); ??
});
```

Comment: You would have to copy a reference to `client` to an object that the other file had a reference too.  However, if they are indeed two different running processes, you may have to use a slightly more complex IPC solution.